# Upddating Multidatespicker 1.6.1 to work with jQuery 1.9+ (.browser depreciated)

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I'm trying to user Multidatespicker, which is at version 1.6.1 for over a year now. When running with jQuery version 1.9+ it doesn't work, and the jQuery migrate tool says that the reason is that the .browser method is depreciated (and no longer included as of 1.9).

After some more research, it seems that it's actually the jQuery datepicker ui widget that is using the .browser method. I tried to download the latest datepicker ui plugin from jqueryui.com, but they bundle the UI Core with the datepicker widget, which doesn't match how the bundled files are in multidatepicker.

My hope was that I could just update the datepicker widget plugin and UI core and that multidatepicker would work. Has anyone done this successfully, or can anyone recommend another multidate picker?

Comment: jQuery Migrate includes $.browser, so why don't you just include Migrate, problem solved ?

Comment: From the jquery migrate page " Ideally this would only be used as a short-term solution, but that's a decision for you to make."
I'd rather a proper solution, but this is what I'm doing at the moment.